# Contact form on Yahoo Small Business Hosting

Tags: php, html, wordpress, hosting, yahoo

I am creating a site on Yahoo Small Business hosting, and am having issues with the PHP contact form that I use on my WordPress install on Bluehost. The form is:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
if(trim($_POST['contactName']) === '') {
    $nameError = 'Please enter your name.';
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $name = trim($_POST['contactName']);
}

if(trim($_POST['email']) === '')  {
    $emailError = 'Please enter your email address.';
    $hasError = true;
} else if (!preg_match("/^[[:alnum:]][a-z0-9_.-]*@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i", trim($_POST['email']))) {
    $emailError = 'You entered an invalid email address.';
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
}

if(!isset($hasError)) {
    $emailTo = get_option('tz_email');
    if (!isset($emailTo) || ($emailTo == '') ){
        $emailTo = 'chris@bingetech.com';
    }
    $subject = '[PHP Snippets] From '.$name;
    $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments: $comments";
    $headers = 'From: '.$name.' <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

    wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $emailSent = true;
}

} ?>
    <div id="contact-wrap">
        <?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true)    
{ ?>
                            <div class="thanks">
                                    <p>Thanks, your email was sent successfully.</p>
                        </div>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                        <?php if(isset($hasError) || isset($captchaError)) { ?>
                            <p class="error">Sorry, an error occurred.<p>
                        <?php } } ?>

                    <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
                        <ul class="formList">
                        <li>
                            <label class="contact_labels" for="contactName">Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="contactName" id="contactName" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['contactName'])) echo $_POST['contactName'];?>" class="required requiredField" />
                            <?php if($nameError != '') { ?>
                                <span class="error"><?=$nameError;?></span>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <label class="contact_labels" for="email">Email:&nbsp;</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email']))  echo $_POST['email'];?>" class="required requiredField email" />
                            <?php if($emailError != '') { ?>
                                <span class="error"><?=$emailError;?></span>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </li>

                        </ul>
                            <div id="subContain">
                            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Ask Away!"></input>
                            </div>


                    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
                </form>
    </div>
```

I have the appropriate header calls and this does work on Bluehost, and from my research it appears Yahoo Small Business hosting can be tricky with contact forms/email. How can I get around this?

Comment: What's the error/problem?

Comment: @Scott Helme Despite the "Success" message, no emails are ever sent.

Comment: Just try to boil it down to the basics, comment out everything and see if you can just make a call to mail() and it will send. If that doesn't work there is something to look at other than your code.

Comment: Is there any special reason why you want to use wp_mail? I have various sites hosted with Yahoo and the standard PHP "mail" works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some plugin instead of your own PHP code. Try Contact form 7 its completely customize-able